Scene in a laundromat where a man's clothes turn pink
First time here but what a great resource! I've got a movie scene in my head which is bugging me as I can't remember the name of the film, so hoping you can help identify it please.
It's an American film I think and relatively recent though I couldn't say when. It involves a guy who is in a public laundromat washing his white clothes. When they're done he opens the machine he pulls out a red item (Bra? Top?) which a neighbouring woman grabs off him without saying anything. He then realises all his clothes have turned pink as a result, and I think the next scene shows him wearing a pink shirt but I could be wrong.... any ideas? All I can find on Google is an episode of Friends and it's not that.

A fairly common trope (it happened on the Simpsons too). Do you remember anything else? The plot or genre or what the actors looked like? And are you sure it was a movie and not a TV show?

This could be Spielberg's Catch Me If You Can from 2002 starring Leonardo DiCaprio and Tom Hanks. I barely remember this scene, but according to the IMDb Goofs section, it's close to your scenario:

When Hanratty is in the laundromat he pulls a red sweater out of the dryer that changes his clothes pink. But, the lady who grabs the sweater from him is also doing a white load. It seems very unlikely that she would have had that sweater in her clothes, and if she did her clothes would have been pink as well from the wash.

Here's the trailer:



